# Appearing the iphone keyboard when the view is loading

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

hai all,

in my iphone application i have a login view with two text fields, one for user name and one for password, after the view appear the user need to tap on one of the text field then only the key board appear so that they can enter text, is there any way to put the keyboard up when the view is loaded (ie, the user can directly start typing- no need to tap the username filed)  and also i would like to move the focus from user name filed to password field when the user taps next button in the key board ,

thanks in advance
shinto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[myTextField becomeFirstResponder]